# clearTimeout does not rest timer to zero

Tags: javascript, timer

I've research many related topics but can't find a solution.  I want to create a script that will redirect to a different page due to inactivity.  I have tried variations of the following script to no avail.

```js
$(function () {
    doStuff();
});


function doStuff () {
    var timer = null;
    
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches touchscreen presses
    window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches touchpad clicks
    window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling with arrow keys
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function logout() {
       document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'the timer reads ' + timer;
    }

   function resetTimer() {
        if(timer){window.clearTimeout(timer);};   
        timer = window.setTimeout(logout, 1000);  // time is in milliseconds
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='status'></div>
```

Instead of resetting the timer to zero when any of the defined events occur, it just increments the existing timer.  Try running the snippet and move the mouse,  etc.  None of the events clears the timer.

I tested my script in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.  I also set up a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bradsmithcpa/sjxn2s6j/

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns you a "timeoutID" which is ***only*** used so you can call [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout).  Your `timer` variable is not a "timer", it's just an internal ID.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  What do you expect `the timer reads _` to say?

Comment: Your code works exactly as I'd expect it to do. The `logout` function isn't called unless 1 second expires without any mouse activity. As Rocket said, I'm not sure what you expected from echoing the timer id.

Comment: I'm writing a user interface that allows someone to upload files to a server.  For security and other considerations I want the page redirected to a to let the user know the page timed-out and needs to refresh the page if needed. I need a timer mechanism to track the inactivity. The purpose of the "timer reads" is just for testing purposes so I can see if the script is working as intended.

Comment: @Brad: Your code works fine.  What's the problem you are having?  What is *your* intended outcome?  If you want an *actual* timer, you're gonna have to make one.  You could save the start/end `Date`s and calculate it, maybe.

Comment: I think this is a matter of my misunderstanding of the timer variable.  Rocket explained it when he said the timeoutID is just an internal id.  I agree the code is fine.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Rocket Hazmatt answered my question by explaining the 'timer' is an internal id.  I misunderstood what the timeoutID represented.